# How to declare new type

Tags: c#, types

How to create new type in c#? For example **byte** has range 0 to 255, but I need new type which would have 0 to 10 range.

Comment: how do you normally create a new type?  public class blah .... Creating a new type to do that seems pretty pointless really....

Comment: Are you sure you need a new type, instead of just input validation?

Comment: How to set range validation and type validation while compiling? For example I can't set string for byte type, I get compilation error. How to do the same for my type?

Comment: Try code contracts in VS. Or use tests to ptevent misuse. Or flog developers who misset constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazing that people want to close this as not a real question!

The answer is that C# does not have a type system that supports checking integer ranges at compile time, except for a few built-in cases: it stops you assigning larger-range numbers to smaller-range numbers. But the ranges for those numbers are pre-defined in the language specification.

Comment: I agree with you. No one gives right answer and closing question without understanding that I ask and even without having answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You create a class that wraps `byte` (or `int`, if you need a larger range).
Then, you define the usual operations - *, /, - ... You can use operator overloading for this.
You add some checks to see if the value remains within the bounds, and throw the appropriate Exception otherwise.
Here's a short example:

```
class LimitedRangeValue
{
    private static readonly int maxval = 10;
    private static readonly int minval = 0;
    private int n;

    public LimitedRangeValue( int n )
    {
        if (n < minval || n > maxval)
            throw new OverflowException();
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static LimitedRangeValue operator +( LimitedRangeValue r1, LimitedRangeValue r2 )
    {
        return new LimitedRangeValue( r1.n + r2.n );
    }

    // Other operators by analogy

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return n.ToString();
    }
}
```

EDIT: As @Andrew Barber points out in the comments, you could use Code Contracts for (extra) validation.

Comment: I think you'll find that C# *does* have operator overloading... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @BradleySmith Thanks! Didn't know that; changed the answer accordingly.